# How can I keep the "Console Drawer" hidden by default every time I open Chrome DevTools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

When I have DevTools open, there is a little button that toggles `Hide Drawer.` and `Show Console.`. Besides being inconsistently named, the 'drawer' is very annoying to me because it takes up so much of the little screen real estate allotted for devtools (i'm bottom docked). How can I keep this 'drawer' closed permanently? Or if I can't do that, can I at least keep the height of it as low as possible? (it returns to a default height every time I open it)

Comment: Are you using Canary? I think it is a bug in Canary. Stable Chrome has the drawer hidden every time you open the DevTools.

Comment: Screenshot? Browser version? It's called "Show console" and "Hide console" in my Chromium browser (v31.0.1650.63).

Comment: Version 32.0.1700.41 m Aura

Comment: apparently my chrome install is part of an a/b test? http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/zmgiVCv9X0A/HXmhMIYzc1YJ

Comment: I'd be happy not to be part of it - you're right the drawer is very annoying and can't be customised. :/

Comment: I'm having this exact problem too. Does anyone know the best way to contact the chrome team about this sort of thing?

Comment: This thing making me angry and I cannot do anything about it

Comment: Same problem here.... so annoying!

Comment: Darko just added an answer to this question. It worked for me.

Comment: It doesn't remember the size you give it, and it also pops up when it detects an error (not just because of emulation).

Comment: In version 32.0.1700.107, it starts off as "Show drawer.", then cycles between "Hide drawer." and "Show console.". (See inspector.js.)

Comment: It seems that a combination of the answers below might be required as was the case for me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I solved same problem removing the flag from "Spoof user agent" option under the "Emulation" tab (I don't even know why it was flagged!).

Comment: I also had to uncheck 'Emulate Screen'

Comment: Under the emulation tab, enabled options are flagged with a blue check on the left side.

Comment: There is no emulation tab.

Answer (score 79):

At least you can press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to toggle the console area hide and show.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me! Simple fixes are the best fixes

Comment: That's not an answer, it keeps popping out everytime the page is refreshed.

Comment: It's annoying press esc every time that you want to hide the console. Should be a way to have the console hide by default (with or without errors)

Comment: If you get rid of it, how do you get it back?

Comment: Every version of Chrome seems to keep making minor changes.

Answer (score 70):

None of the previous answers worked for me. All of my emulation tab options are cleared/reset. I'm not sure if it's new but it turns out that there is a "Toggle emulation" button on the left side, next to the search icon. Mine was blue so I clicked on it to make it non-blue. Screenshot is below. Now, all is happy. That was so frustrating!

[image: "Toggle emulation" button highlighted in red]

Comment: This is the one that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 23):

Apparently there is a show / hide console button next to the setting button.
info and screenshot here - https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#opening_the_console

Comment: This moved, now you just click the three dots in the upper right and Show/Hide console is a menu option.

Answer (score 21):

My problem was that the Console was enabled in the chrome menu, you can turn it off by clicking on the Console option in the dev tools settings:

[image: Turn off Console]

Comment: Hallelujah, out of ALL of the above, this worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

**THIS SOLUTION NO LONGER WORKS WITH NEW CHROME VERSIONS. THE ICON WAS REMOVED.
The working solution was pasted above by Sigma. *Pressing the ESC key will toggle the visibility of the panel.***

I notice the majority of these answers are over a year old. I had a similiar issue and it's August 2015.

I was overlooking a simple icon: The >_ next to the gear.
[image]

You can see the video of the window being shown and hidden to confirm this is the same issue:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOC863BxZNM&hd=1

Comment: As of August 2015 (Chrome Version 46.0.2478.0 dev-m (64-bit) on Windows), this solved the issue for me, thanks!

Comment: This is the most up to date answer

Comment: I believe the reason the majority of people randomly getting this drawer open is because they are hitting the escape key. The Escape key will toggle this window when the developer console is open.

Comment: That icon is no longer there.

Comment: For me it seems to want to pop back open every time I refresh the page, it's very irritating because I have the tools docked to the bottom and it blocks out almost the entire area.

Answer (score 6):

When the "drawer" is open look into the "emulation" tab, then click on "reset." Close dev tool (F12) and then reopen it (F12). The "drawer" is hidden by default.

My Chrome Version: 32.0.1700.77

The response of Darko works, I propose another way to solve this problem.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

click **Restore Defaults and Reload** in Dev tools Setting right bottom

my chrome version is 37

in my case reset in emulation does not worked although i had tried it recently and it was the root cause

Answer (score 2):

In latest chrome there is a "Show What's New after each update" setting (preferences->appearance). Once you untick it, the console finally won't pop up anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It is because **`Spoof User Agent`** is enabled in your `Emulation`-tab in the drawer.

**Deselect the options below**

[image: The spoof user agent]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and also a frame around the page with pixels lenght of page (kind of rulers if you use PSD) with options for device width. I've solved clicking on restore default options. Hope can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had to uncheck that box shown in circle in the newest chrome version (38.*).

[image: Hide console]

Answer (score 0):

If you ever right click one of the dev tool tabs and do "move to bottom" then you have just enabled the horrid "console drawer" which is the bottom set of tabs. To fix this open the dev tools (F12), then click the ellipsis (...), then click show console drawer. A second set of tabs opens. Right click all tabs there except for the console and select move to top.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

- Chrome (114.0.5735.110): Simply click that `x` to close the drawer. (See screenshot below)
  [image: chrome]
- Edge (114.0.1823.43): Click that collapse button. (See screenshot below)
  [image: edge]
- Last resort (incase none of the above works for you)

  1. Click `F12` or whatever your shortcut is to toggle devtools.
  2. Close all tabs except `Console` on the drawer.
  3. Switch to `Console` panel at the top.
  4. Now when you re-open devtools, the drawer should be minimized by default.