# Google Chrome dev tools automatically opens the 'drawer' pane

Tags: macos, google-chrome-devtools

As of a few days ago, whenever I open the developer tools in Chrome on OSX the 'drawer' automatically opens - 2nd screen shot

The icon in blue shows/hides the drawer (now defaults to on) - First screen shot

[image: The icon in blue shows/hides the drawer (now defaults to on)]

[image]

This is so annoying and I cant figure out a way to stop this behaviour. It never did this before....

Comment: I agree it is very annoying, but the new emulator section is pretty cool. I haven't found a workaround yet.

Comment: @ChrisMuench thank christ im not the only one having this issue! Hopefully someone comes and saves us from the pain lol

Comment: As this is still an issue at least for OS X and no workarounds help (pressing escape after every page load is not a workaround), i filed a bug as https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=624038.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was annoying me to no end and I could never figure out why it was automatically opening. Apparently the fix, at least in my case, is that I went into the Emulation tab inside of the drawer and disabled any of the overrides. Everything in blue is highlighted as an override. Disabling those seems to have fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Works!  see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819685/how-can-i-keep-the-console-drawer-hidden-by-default-every-time-i-open-chrome-d

Answer (score 6):

Offering [Phil Rykoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284364/phil-rykoff)'s comment as a solution...

**Disabling JavaScript source maps** seems to do the trick for me.

`Settings` > `Enable JavaScript source maps`

I was getting an error parsing my source maps so this could well be the cause for those with similar errors:

> Failed to parse SourceMap: https://myapp/vendor.map

Comment: A +1 for this. Specifically the console appears to show an error, which is different behaviour from "why does this always appear?". You can test it by opening the inspector on another web page (e.g. this one), with no errors, the console does not automatically open again.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution press the "Escape" key when you're on the Developer Tools

Comment: This. This. This. It's so obvious that it hurt when I pressed "Escape" and it disappeared.

Comment: Pressing escape every time you load a page is not a "solution."

Comment: @hackel you don't have to press it every time. may be you're on OSX it's a known bug, it keeps opening every time.

Comment: Actually, I don't believe this is a bug. It seems that the escape key is just bound to the "Toggle Drawer" command and executing this command actually modifies some persisted state. You can see this if you view the current keyboard shortcuts inside of devtools.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a setting under `Appearance` -> `Show 'Emulation'/'Rendering' view in console drawer` which will turn them off by default. But if you have some overrides then the panel still popup when you open Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the DevTools, click the hamburger-icon.
2. Click 'Hide console'

[image: How to hide the console and keep it hidden]

Comment: This does not work on 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit) OS-X. The Drawer reopens every time the page is refreshed.

Comment: Confirmed, the latest 51 update on OSX resets the drawer view on every reload. I can't find any setting that relates to this behavior (and that is preserved across page views), and all fixes/workarounds posted for the same issue in previous Chrome versions either are not present any more, or do not fix the issue.

Comment: Works on 51.0.2704.106 Windows. Unfortunately does not work on OS X

Comment: In my case, it was related to source maps. Disabling css + js source maps made the console hide for good.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Ed's solution (which did fix my problem) the issue appears to be that the whatever page you are viewing is generating a console error- which in this case just happens to be a SourceMap error.

Because the default tab on the Dev Tools pane is "Elements" it appears that Chrome opens the console drawer so that the error message is visible when you reload. Rearranging the tabs in the Dev Tools so that console is the first item solves the issue, and I could re-enable SourceMap errors.