# How to keep the console closed when using inspect element

Tags: google-chrome, console

How can I keep the console window closed every time I inspect element in Chrome?

The only question I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819685/how-can-i-keep-the-console-drawer-hidden-by-default-every-time-i-open-chrome-d)

But all answers are old. Every time I inspect element I have to close the window manually or press esc, which is really annoying.

None of the answers in the link I posted above work for me or are irrelevant because the buttons were removed/changed.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the Console completely just click the 3 dots in the top right corner of the **DevTools** console and click **Hide Console**.

A workaround that I found is resize the console element down to the bottom in this way you are free to see the elements of your page more carefully.

Comment: I noticed the button, but when I press is, refresh the page and inspect element again, the console is opened again.

Comment: Are you sure, that you selected the Elements tab in the DevTools console?
It would be great if you upload a screenshot of what you see

Comment: I'll add a screenshot